# Finding no argument in driver class in Java

Tags: java, switch-statement, primitive

I've tried so many things and have spent countless hours on this issue without any luck. What I have is a class that needs to get the month which the user inputs as an int and use a switch statement to convert into a string(the corresponding month). I have tried many things, but for some reason I get the error that the required and found arguments differ in length.
(I have tried many things like simply using S.O.P, toString, and others but nothing has worked so far)

Summary: Turn an integer into a string through a switch statement.

Here is my driver class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * Write a description of class TestMonthDays here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class TestMonthDays
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Creates scanner
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Brings the MonthDays class into the test class
        MonthDays date;
        date = new MonthDays();

        //Asks user for number 1-12 and if its not between that range then asks the user again
        System.out.print ("Enter the number of a month [1-12]: ");
        int numberMonth = keyboard.nextInt();

        while (!(numberMonth >= 1 && numberMonth <= 12))
        {
            System.out.print ("Please enter a number of a month between 1 and 12: ");
            numberMonth = keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        //Gets the year that the user inputs
        System.out.print ("\nEnter the number of a year, greater than 0: ");
        int year = keyboard.nextInt();

        while (year < 0)
        {
            System.out.print ("Please enter the number of a year that is greater than 0: ");
            year = keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println ("\nThe number of days in " + date.getMonth() + ", " + year + " is: ");
    }
}
```

And here is the specific method and constructor in my other class that I am struggling with:

```
/**
 * Write a description of class MonthDays here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class MonthDays
{
    // instance variables 
    int month;
    int year;
    String thisMonth;
    public void date() //Default Constructor
    {
        month = 0;
        year = 0;
        thisMonth = "";
    }


    public String getMonth(int month)
    {
        switch (month) 
        {
            case 1:
                thisMonth = ("January");
                break;
            case 2: 
               thisMonth = ("February");
                break;
            case 3:
                thisMonth = ("March");
                break;
            case 4:
                thisMonth = ("April");
                break;
            case 5:
                thisMonth = ("May");
                break;
            case 6: 
                thisMonth = ("June");
                break;
            case 7:
                thisMonth = ("July");
                break;
            case 8:
                thisMonth = ("August");
                break;
            case 9:
                thisMonth = ("September");
                break;
            case 10:
                thisMonth = ("October");
                break;
            case 11:
                thisMonth = ("November");
                break;
            case 12:
                thisMonth = ("December");
                break;
        }
        return thisMonth;
    }
}
```

Comment: `date.getMonth() ` must be `date.getMonth(numberMonth)`.

Answer (score 0):

First

```
public void date() //Default Constructor
```

is **wrong**. A constructor name must match the class name, and is **not** `void`.

```
public MonthDays() // <-- No-arg constructor, if you provide any constructor
                   //     there is no default constructor.
```

Second you should separate the logic for determining a month name, from setting the value. And I would prefer a `static` method and `Map` for that. Like,

```
private static Map<Integer, String> monthMap = new HashMap<>();
static {
    String[] names = { "January", "February", "March", "April", //
            "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", //
            "November", "December" };
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        monthMap.put(i + 1, names[i]);
    }
}

// Could be public, just a utility method
private static String getMonthName(int month) {
    return monthMap.getOrDefault(month, "Unknown");
}
```

Then, use something like

```
public String getMonth() {
    return getMonthName(this.month);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling getMonth Method with no args. Just change

System.out.println ("\nThe number of days in " + date.getMonth() + ", " + year + " is: ");

to

System.out.println ("\nThe number of days in " + date.getMonth(numberMonth) + ", " + year + " is: ");